# Criterion for series convergence - is there a rule such that?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I didnt find it on the internet, but I remember that I saw it somewhere. 
There are the known tests:

if $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\sqrt[n]{a_n}\:<1$$ then $$\lim _{n\to \infty }a_n\:=\:0$$

if $$\lim \:_{n\to \:\infty \:}\sqrt[n]{a_n}\:>1$$ then $$\lim _{n\to \infty }a_n\:=\:\infty$$

The additional rule that I remember is if we allready have a limit that is written with the square, then if:

$$\lim \:\:_{n\to \:\:\infty \:\:}\:\frac{\left(a_{n+1}\:\right)}{a_n}=L\:$$ then the limit is also:
$$\lim \:\:_{n\to \:\:\infty \:\:}\sqrt[n]{a_n}\:=L$$

Is my memory serves me correctly ?

Comment: or maybe just L>0, i dont remember for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first two "yes." (I assume you talk about positive $a_n$ if not there is an issue with the $n$-th root.)

Note that if $a_n$ would not tend to $0$, then there would be some $c>0$ such that a subsequence $(a_{n_i})$ is bounded below by $c$.

But then taking the $n$-th root and recalling that $c^{1/n}$ tends to $1$ for every fixed $c>0$ we get a contradiction to the assumption that the limit is less than $1$.

For the second claim the same argument can be used, just reversing inequalites essentially.

It is also true that if the sequence of ratios convergences then the sequence of $n$-roots converges to the same limit. To see this note that from the convergence of the ratios you get for every $\epsilon > 0$ 
$$ (L- \epsilon)^{n-n_0} a_{n_0} \le  a_n \le (L+ \epsilon)^{n-n_0} a_{n_0}   $$
for all $n \ge n_0(\epsilon)$.
Then taking $n$-th roots and some short argument yield the result. (This is for $L>0$, in case $L=0$ replace the lower bound by $0$.)

Comment: You helpem me to get remembered in what it is supose to be. Here, fixed it. IS it correct now ?

Comment: That's great. I updated the post. Only next time please do not change the post in such a way that the answer becomes partly incomprehensible. That is it would have been better to add the second additional claim rather then to replace the original. But it is not a big deal.